# Displaying image from physical path to crystal report

Tags: c#

I can fetch many customer records from the database and display them in crystal report but how can I fetch every customer pictures from physical path and display them in crystal report?

Comment: @RafaSashi: please don't use `code spans` to highlight words -- these are only meant for the use of code in sentences, for example: "_You can use a `<div>` element to separate the two._"

Comment: @RafaSashi: no worries :)

Comment: See the video: [How to Show Images Dynamically into Crystal Report by Image Path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmzudQpRB_0)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Crystal Reports included with Visual Studio, this is not supported. It will display images stored in a db field, but not from a url.